# Error: void value not ignored as it ought be

Tags: c

I don´t know how to solve this error in my code. 
The error seems to be in `if (EnemigosMueve(e))`. The compiler says: `error: void value not ignored as it ought be`.

this is the code in Enemigos.c

```
   void EnemigosMueve(Enemigos e)
{
    while(e->sig!=NULL)
    {
        if (EnemigoMueve(e->sig->e))
        {
            Enemigos aux = e->sig;
            e->sig = e->sig->sig;
            EnemigoLibera(aux->e);
            free(aux);
        }
        else e = e->sig;
    }
}
```

and here is the code in main:

```
if (EnemigosMueve(e)) {
            EnemigosLibera(e);
            if (rand()%FRECENEMIGOS==0) EnemigosInsertaNuevaEnemigo(e,EnemigoCrea(eImagen,WENEMIGO,HENEMIGO,rand()%(wPantalla-WENEMIGO),0,VXENEMIGO,VYENEMIGO));
    }
```

if someone needs more information, just tell me and i'll post it.

Comment: And what is the error/where does it occur???

Comment: Compile with *warnings* enabled - you're using an implicit function declaration somehow...

Comment: Your code is loaded with compiler warnings and errors. Turn warnings on and fix them first.

Comment: My code only have one error and its that one. Error: void value not ignored as it ought be in the "if (EnemigosMueve(e)).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `EnemigosMueve` does not return values, so `if (EnemigosMueve(e))` is wrong, as your compiler is telling you

```
error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
if (EnemigoMueve(e->sig->e))
    ^
```